# Highlight the links without using dropdown

Tags: php, css, html

I have navmenus `Home | Vendors | About | Contact` and i have *Fruits* and *Vegetables* as pages. And these pages are added using `href` under the Vendors page. I am using the id as a link.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link(21); ?>"> Fruits </a>
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link(64); ?>"> Vegetables </a>

/* CSS */
.current_page_item, .current_page_parent {
    background-color: yellow;
    }
```

If you click those links it will go to the relevant page, but the `Vendors` menu is not highlighted. But if i use the *Fruits* and *Vegetables* as a dropdown menu for `Vendors`, the css works.

I do not want to show the dropdown, but i want to highlight the navmenu. How do i do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

I found it by using the `<?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?>` with customizing the args to display only selected children by id.

```
$args = array (
    'title_li'  => '',
    'child_of'  => $post->ID,
    'include'  => 47
    )

<h4> <?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?> </h4>
```

and setting the css to target the current and its parent using wordpress default css.

```
.current-menu-item, .current-page-ancestor {
    /* css */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box WordPress does not provide a CSS class that you could use to target the parent of the current page. You could either use a custom walker or create a function that hooks to `nav_menu_css_class` to add a `current-page-ancestor` class to parent pages of the page you're on.

See: https://gist.github.com/gerbenvandijk/5253921

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved it by setting the child pages to its parent navmenu in the dashboard and to highlight i use the default WordPress css `.current-menu-item, .current-page-ancestor { }`